# How do I get conditionals (If/Else) to check if buttons were clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way of returning different results if a different button is clicked. I have two buttons which are to return values depending on what the user clicks. Here is a code that is close to what mine looks like.

```js
$(() => {
  const $btn1 = $("#btn1"),
        $btn2 = $("#btn2");

  let result = 0;
  function fetchResult() {
    if("button1 is clicked"){ //Of course, that isn't the condition being tested
      result = 1 + 2;
    } else if ("button2 is clicked") { //And neither is this
      result = 3 + 4;
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
    return result;
  }

  $("#result").html(fetchResult);
});
```

```css
#result {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-lg" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: do in $("#btn1").click method of jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an event listener to handle click events for this to work:

```
$btn1.on('click', function() {
    console.log('button 1 clicked');
});

$btn2.on('click', function() {
    console.log('button 2 clicked');
});
```

Or you could add the event to the `.btn` class and determine which one is clicked based on the element's id:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   if (this.id === 'btn1') {
      console.log('button 1 clicked');
   } else if (this.id === 'btn2') {
      console.log('button 2 clicked');
   }
});
```

The latter approach would probably be better for your particular use case.

Comment: Thank you!! Precisely what I was looking for(the latter part of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event:

```js
$("#btn1").on('click', () => {
    $("#result").html(1 + 2);
});
$("#btn2").on('click', () => {
    $("#result").html(2 + 3);
});
```

```css
#result {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-lg" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        // or what ever your code ....
    });
```

Do not forget to add jQuery tag in html file

Answer (score 0):

What about just set variable when some button clicked..
Of course, in your code you will also need to run a function that sends the result to the screen when the button is pressed

```
$(() => {
  let btn1Clicked = false,
      btn2Clicked = false 
  const $btn1 = $("#btn1").click(()=>btn1Clicked = true),
        $btn2 = $("#btn2").click(()=>btn2Clicked = true);

  let result = 0;
  function fetchResult() {
    if( btn1Clicked ){ //Of course, that isn't the condition
      result = 1 + 2;
    } else if (btn2Clicked ) { //And this isn't the condition either
      result = 3 + 4;
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }
    return result;
  }

  $(document).on('#btn1, #btn2', function(){
   fetchResult()
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could assign  onclick events to both of the button individually like

```
$(#btnId1).on('click',function(){
//do your thing here
});
$(#btnId2).on('click',function(){
    //do your thing here
});
```